# Database: search photos by multiple keywords (many to many relationship)

Tags: sql, database, select, many-to-many, keyword-search

Gallery with pictures, each has keywords and I need to retrieve photos by given set of keywords.

There is many to many relationship with 3 tables. For simplicity let's presume the tables are already joined as you would in many2many. The JOIN is not the issue here.

How would you go about looking up photos, that have specific set of keywords. For example photos, that has "portrait" AND "sport" keywords.

My best idea so far is:

```
SELECT photoName,keyword,COUNT(photoName) as photoOccurence FROM joinedTables WHERE keyword IN ('portrait', 'keywords') GROUP BY photoName HAVING photoOccurence = 2;
```

Explanation:

Find all occurences of given keywords. Group by photoName and filter (HAVING) only photoNames, that appear the same number of times as is the count of keywords given. In this case 2.

Any better/other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT photoName FROM joinedTables WHERE keyword = 'portrait'
INTERSECT
SELECT photoName FROM joinedTables WHERE keyword = 'keywords'
-- ...
```

and a version with cte:

```
WITH joinedTables AS (
   SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   JOIN ...
   JOIN ...
)
SELECT photoName FROM joinedTables WHERE keyword = 'portrait'
INTERSECT
SELECT photoName FROM joinedTables WHERE keyword = 'keywords'
-- ...
```

Comment: thanks, that is a nice idea :-)... too bad I am using MySQL. Still I feel the query would get quite long and messy for more complex conditions and more keywords - it needs to be dynamic